# Cannot use dependency jboss-javaee-6.0 in my Maven project

Tags: maven, ejb, java-ee-6

I have set up a maven project with JBoss 7.1.1 and I want to use JavaEE libraries. 
In the root pom.xml I have set:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>jboss</id>
        <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

I have this in the root pom.xml and and in the ejb maven module´s pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

When I do a `maven clean install` I get this error:

```
Failed to execute goal on project myproject-ejb: Could not resolve dependencies for project myproject:myproject-ejb:ejb:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.jboss.spec:jboss-javaee-6.0:jar:3.0.2.Final in https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of jboss has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

What´s up with my configuration?

**EDIT 1**
If I remove the jboss repository from the root pom.xml I get this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project myproject-ejb: Could not resolve dependencies for project myproject:myproject-ejb:ejb:1.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.jboss.spec:jboss-javaee-6.0:jar:3.0.2.Final, xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.1.jbossorg-2: Could not find artifact org.jboss.spec:jboss-javaee-6.0:jar:3.0.2.Final in central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is caused by a [bug](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBBUILD-708) in Xalan POM file. The following [workaround](https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/xalan-is-missing-from-repository) fixed the problem for me:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Required by jboss-javaee-6.0:3.0.2.Final (https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBBUILD-708) --> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xalan</groupId>
            <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: Your solution and this repository worked fine for me!

https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/

Answer (score 0):

The given dependency for jboss-javaee-6.0 is available from [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search|gav|1|g%3A%22org.jboss.spec%22%20AND%20a%3A%22jboss-javaee-6.0%22) so there is no need to give a separate repository.

Based on the error message you need to delete a particular location from your location maven repository (usually in $HOME/.m2/repository) in this case the folder **org/jboss/**. Afterwards you need to rebuild your project.

Comment: I tried to remove the jboss repository, but I got another error. See my `EDIT 1` above. I also removed .m2/repository and rebuilt the project.

Comment: You used the wrong type **org.jboss.spec:jboss-javaee-6.0:jar:3.0.2.Final** this references a jar file which is not the case. You need to reference the pom artifact (type pom) in dependency.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-javaee-all-6.0</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2.Final</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

But I see [here](http://www.mastertheboss.com/cdi/java-ee-6-cdi-example-application) that something like the following may also work:

```
<dependency>    
    <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-javaee-web-6.0</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>    
</dependency>
```