# should all dependencies be explicitily mentioned in child pom if the parent pom has Java EE BOM dependency?

Tags: hibernate, maven, jakarta-ee, jboss, resteasy

In our project, we have separate modules for REST layer, EJB layer and domain (Entity) layer.

Here is the dependency on our REST layer:

```
            <dependency>
               <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
               <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
                <artifactId>resteasy-jettison-provider</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
                <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <!-- Resteasy Server Cache -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
                <artifactId>resteasy-cache-core</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
                <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
            </dependency>
```

**Q1:** Is there a single dependency of `org.jboss.resteasy` that provides all of these? Any possibility for simplification? should all these dependencies be explicitly declared? If not, what does RestEasy provides some by default? In fact, I use JBoss AS 6. so these dependencies are only for compile time. Their scope is `provided` anyway.

Same holds for our Domain layer:

```
</dependency>
                <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

                <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

                <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

**Q2**: why are these declared explicitly in our pom.xml? shouldn't one dependency on hibernate provides defaults for others.

**Q3** Is the following an effective way of refactoring (using Jboss bom) ? Have one dependency in parent pom.xml and each modules just inherit from parent. In this way, child pom.xml is simplified and short. what is the downside of this? will I get all the dependencies I provided explicitly in each of REST and domain layer above.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.bom.eap</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0-with-resteasy</artifactId>
        <version>${jboss.bom.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will give you everything you need:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.bom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0-with-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.7.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-all-6.0</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xalan</groupId>
            <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

You get everything that is in Java EE 6 (all API's). If you want some functionality that is specific to RestEasy, you need to add dependencies for that.

The Xalan dependency is needed because of a bug, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16300544/cannot-use-dependency-jboss-javaee-6-0-in-my-maven-project) post.

For Java EE 7 on WildFly 8.2 use this dependencies:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.bom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0-with-all</artifactId>
            <version>8.2.0.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-javaee-all-7.0</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: why do you need both org.jboss.spec and org.jboss.bom? shouldn't either one be enough?

Comment: The BOM is just the bill of materials. It is usefull when you add Jboss specific dependencies. You don't need to find out which exact version of the dependency is running in your Jboss server. The version is populated from the BOM. So omit the version tag. For this specific example the BOM is not needed, but I think it's good practice to add it anyway.

Comment: Just the BOM will not be enough, you absolutely need the spec.

Comment: will this include RestEasy, Hibernate, Resteasy-Jackson provider etc?  how do I know what are the defaults it provides. Thank you

Comment: No. This includes all [Java EE 6 api's](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/javaee6technologies-1955512.html). What is in the JSR's you get, what is specific to the RestEasy or Hibernate implementation you don't get. So if you want to be platforrm agnostic this is all you should use. Other implementations of the JSR's (i.e. MoXy, Eclipselink) should be working as well. You need to add the specific implementation as a dependency when you are using features that are specific to the implementation.

Comment: Thanks!. I get it. but JBoss ships with implementation of JAX-RS and JPA which are (I suppose) RestEasy and Hibernate.  For example, when I use JAX-RS and produce JSON serialization, Jackson will handle JSON serialization in response, Jackson is packaged with RestEasy which in turn is provided by Jboss container

Comment: I guess you have to add jackson. I am working with Java EE 7 on WildFly 8 so I get JSR-353 (JSON-P). No need to add a Jackson implementation anymore.

Comment: wonderful. I am using Java EE 7 on WildFly too. so can I replace the above 6.0 with 7.0 in your answer and get everything? or use wildfly bom? please suggest