# wildfly quickstart fails from the offset

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, jboss, maven-3, wildfly

i just downloaded wildfly 9.02 with the quickstarts and the jboss developer studio. I am a total newbie to jboss, i am following the guide on github
https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/ to build and deploy the sources. i got my maven installed (v 3.3.3) with java 8. settings.xml copied to my $HOME/.m2 directory but it seems to me that the urls of the artifcats are all broken

```
[ERROR]   The project org.wildfly.quickstarts:wildfly-helloworld:10.0.0-SNAPSHOT (C:\jboss\quickstart\helloworld\pom.xml) has 4 errors
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable import POM: Could not transfer artifact org.jboss.spec:jboss-javaee-7.0:pom:1.0.3.Final 
from/to jboss-earlyaccess-repository (http://maven.repository.redhat.com/earlyaccess/all/): 
Connect to maven.repository.redhat.com:80 [maven.repository.redhat.com/104.66.178.195] failed: Connection timed out: connect @ line 66, column 25 -> 
[Help 2]
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for javax.enterprise:cdi-api:jar is missing. @ line 79, column 21
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' fororg.jboss.spec.javax.annotation:jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec:jar is missing. @ line 87, column 21
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' fororg.jboss.spec.javax.servlet:jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec:jar is missing. @ line 94, column 21
[ERROR]
```

I am supposing something is messed up there because i can't be the only one having this.

appreciate all the help.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is maven that is giving you a problem. It says that the artifact:
`org.jboss.spec:jboss-javaee-7.0:pom:1.0.3.Final` cannot be found in the `maven.repository.redhat.com:80`, as you can see [here](https://maven.repository.redhat.com/earlyaccess/org/jboss/spec/).

What you need to do is remove the redhat maven repository that is somewhere added, so the artifacts are resolved from the standard maven central repository, which does provide this artifact as you see [here](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.jboss.spec%22)

Comment: there was indeed an issue with my proxy configuration that prevented downloading the artifacts. that's fixed but i still have issues. It seems that the poms are not up to date?!! we have references to org.jboss.quickstart.eap in some places and to org.wildfly.quickstart in others!! the helloworld-mbean is an example of that: it's got org.jboss.quickstart.eap at the root and org.wildfly.quickstart in the modules!! furthermore, both can be find nowhere in the redhat repositories... if you can't get the examples to work out of the box, so much for having them in the first place..

Comment: sorry correction: the helloworld-mbean has org.wildfly.quickstarts and version 10.0.0-SNAPSHOT at the root, org.jboss.quickstarts.eap and version 7.0.0-SNAPSHOT in parent tag in the modules. i am going through them one by one. tedious and frustrating...

Comment: Okay. Replace your pom with the generic pom (second one) that I posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28055444/should-all-dependencies-be-explicitily-mentioned-in-child-pom-if-the-parent-pom/28067413#28067413 That should work.

Comment: compilation is fine, deployment is a whole different story...

    _{"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.de
fault-host./wildfly-carmart" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
     _jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./wildfly-carmart: java.la
ng.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:_
     _org/infinispan/commons/configuration/attributes/AttributeInitializer_

This is simply unbelievable

Comment: That looks like a new problem. Can you mark this answer and open a new question? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10243/asking-a-follow-up-question#answer-10245

Comment: @kfc I've pushed fixed build of wildfly quickstarts that is not consistent again.

Comment: @MartijnBurger will do

Comment: Can you post the link to the new question?