# wildfly quickstarts fail to deploy

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly

### Some wildfly quickstart modules fail to deploy with numerous errors

This is a followup on [wildfly quickstart fails from the offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33614324/wildfly-quickstart-fails-from-the-offset) i asked earlier. 
The problem i had identified with the some modules was the inconsistency of the parent and child poms, once i solved that i tried to deploy the modules as the github page explains, but i got deployment errors( mostly ClassNotFoundException exceptions) for the following modules:

**carmart**

**carmart-tx**

**cmt**

**deltaspike**

**ejb-security-interceptors**

**ejb-security-plus**

**helloworld-mdb-propertysubstitution**

**inter-app**

**kitchensink-html5-mobile**

Then I stopped trying to find what others were not deploying..

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is basically reporting an issue with a jboss community project. It is not specific to one issue, so there is no one specific answer to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've reviewed the issues in reported quickstarts and I can confirm that some of them are issues but most of them work just fine.

carmart, carmart-tx & deltaspike ones ware actually broken but are fixed now.

Others work just fine, but the require some setup of the server before you can run them. All that is in detail described in README.md of each one of them.

But I do agree with @CoolBeans that any issues like that should be reported to repository (GH issues) directly or issues.jboss.org jira under WildFly project.